# Python: Print nested function return value

Tags: python

This does print "None", I want it to print "True", I do not want to alter the last line of the code block.

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        return True
print(outer())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`outer` only defines a function, it doesn't call it.  If you want `outer` to return the result of `inner`, you need to do that:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        return True
    return inner()
```

There is no way to make `outer` return `True` without altering it.  (Note that you don't have to modify `inner`.)

Comment: Sorry forgot that inner call, edited my question now. Still same results. Did you test your own code before answering here?

Comment: @AchmedDurangi: When I run your updated code, it prints `True`.  Did you test it before asking?

Comment: Thanks for verifying, turns out I forgot to add a "return" in front of a recursive call in that construct (not posted above). But your verification helped me solving the problem!